# I need help getting a number from a <p> element with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, function, dom

I am new in JavaScript. I have 3 numbers with 10 digits in a `<p>` tag, and I would like to select and convert them to a link. I was able to get the numbers and convert them to link, but I am getting all 3 numbers at the same time as one link, it would be great if I can get some help, Thank you

Here is my code:

```
<p>
What 0123456789 exactly is this Worker thread module, 9876543210 and why do we need it? 9768352461 In this post, we will talk about the historical reasons concurrency is implemented in JavaScript and Node.js, the problems we might find, current solutions, and the future of parallel processing with Worker threads.
</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML; 
  var link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+text;
  var rgx = /\d{10}/g;
  var text = str.match(rgx);
  var res = str.replace(rgx, '<a href= "'+link+'">"'+text+'"</a>');
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = res;
}

myFunction();

</script>
```

Comment: *I have 3 numbers with 10 digits in a <p> tag* <-- No, you have a single string of text in a `<p>` *element*. HTML has exactly one data type: `string`. If you need to treat the strings as numbers in JavaScript, they will need to be converted.

Comment: You are right they are strings. I would just like to get the strings but only show one of the strings as a link and not all of the one matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture certain expressions in regex. Then you can get value from that group by using `$` and a group number. There's only one group so in this case there'll be `$1`;

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
  var link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=$1";
  var rgx = /(\d{10})/g; // () wraps an expression in a group
  var text = str.match(rgx);
  var res = str.replace(rgx, '<a href= "' + link + '">$1</a>');
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = res;
}
```

More about capturing groups: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges

Edit: I found even a simpler way - if you want to refer to the whole expression you don't need to create a group. To insert matched value you can use `$&`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
  var link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=$&";
  var rgx = /\d{10}/g;
  var text = str.match(rgx);
  var res = str.replace(rgx, '<a href= "' + link + '">$&</a>');
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I’ll try this option too, always good to know diferentes way, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(rgx);
```

returns an array of matching strings. If you want to use only on item of the array, you can reference to the index (like `text[0]`) or you can i.e. loop over the array with `text.forEach`

or you can map over it and generate links like this:

```
let links = text.map((string) => { return `www.yourlink.com/${string}`})
```

Answer (score 0):

in your replace statement use text instead of rgx

```
var res = str.replace(text, '<a href= "'+link+'">"'+text+'"</a>');
```

that way you only replace the instance of the matched text instead of all the rgx matches

EDIT
this should do it

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML; 
  var rgx = /\d{10}/g;
  var text = str.match(rgx);
  
  for (i=0; i<text.length; i++) { 
     var link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+text[i];
     str = str.replace(text[i], '<a href= "'+link+'">"'+text[i]+'"</a>');
  }
  
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = str;
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: I've tried that and I always get this response

index.html:28 Uncaught TypeError: text.replace is not a function
    at myFunction (index.html:28)
    at index.html:32
myFunction @ index.html:28
(anonymous) @ index.html:32

Comment: not sure why you are getting an error.  
i add a full example which tested the above code and it works with the example you gave.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see the code above. You are right, it works perfectly, Thank you for you help, that's exactly what I wanted, Thank you